# Initial state for a 3-body problem to create Figure 8 [ restricted to 2D ]

Tags: solar-system, gravity, astrophysics, n-body-simulations

I've made an n-body simulation solution using the naive algorithm of O(n^2) in my library ChelseaaJS.
I was trying to make some pleasing 3 Body simulations.
I wanna do the 8 figure thing.
I know it's a 3D simulation restricted to 2D to create 8-figure as given in the famous research paper on the same.
I wanted to know if there is any particular initial state of the system in 2d i.e. given position and speed of masses.

Example of the n-body simulation:
This is just a basic solar system, nothing fancy.
I will put it live if anyone wants to use it, tweak it.

[image]

EDIT :
Here is the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511219 [thanks to
@PM 2Ring]
and I want to make something like :
[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to Astronomy SE! What famous research paper are you referring to? Could you edit the question and add a link to it? I think it could be useful to understand what kind of 8-figure you are trying to obtain

Comment: I assume you're talking about Cris Moore's work: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0511219 https://sites.santafe.edu/~moore/gallery.html

Comment: I just added the link to the paper (the same as given by @PM 2Ring) and I added a photo of what I mean by 8 figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial condition are supposedly given in table 1 of Simó, C. (2001). *New Families of Solutions in N-Body Problems*, however I couldn't decipher the y position of the first and second bodies from there.

I found a slightly different version of the initial conditions in [this website](http://www.artcompsci.org/msa/web/vol_1/v1_web/node45.html):

```
r[0][0] = 0.9700436;
r[0][1] = -0.24308753;
r[0][2] = 0;
v[0][0] = 0.466203685;
v[0][1] = 0.43236573;
v[0][2] = 0;

r[1][0] = -r[0][0];
r[1][1] = -r[0][1];
r[1][2] = -r[0][2];
v[1][0] = v[0][0];
v[1][1] = v[0][1];
v[1][2] = v[0][2];

r[2][0] = 0;
r[2][1] = 0;
r[2][2] = 0;
v[2][0] = -2*v[0][0];
v[2][1] = -2*v[0][1];
v[2][2] = -2*v[0][2];
```

Comment: This seems to be perfect, i tried recreating it an there its not holding up, something's really off, I was wondering if you could spare a lil bit of time and try to make a model for this in some software, because I still cant throttle the time stamp in my library, it runs on a dt= 1/144 sec.

Comment: I tried a bit of debugging my values and turns out there's some miscalibration for gravity and velocity.

Comment: anyway, I'll put the code live in some time

Comment: @BeetranDahiya have you tried running the code that is shown in the website I linked? If that doesn't work, the problem might be in the initial conditions. Otherwise you could try to use this working version to fix your code